# C# Expression, Accessing Property

Tags: c#, filter, iqueryable

I am trying to build a filter method for IQueryable Type,

I could achieve this for ex:
query = query.Filter(UsersListId, e => e.UserId);

```
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T, TSearch>(this IQueryable<T> query, List<TSearch> list, Expression<Func<T, TSearch>> props)
        {
            if (list == null || list.Count == 0)
            {
                return query;
            }
            var propertyPath = props.Body.ToString().Replace(props.Parameters[0] + ".", string.Empty);
            var containsMethod = typeof(List<TSearch>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(TSearch) });
        ConstantExpression constlist = Expression.Constant(list);
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "Entity");
        var newvalue = GetPropertyValue(param, propertyPath);
        var body = Expression.Call(constlist, containsMethod, newvalue);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
        return query.Where(exp);
    }

    public static MemberExpression GetPropertyValue(ParameterExpression parExp, string propertyPath)
    {
        var properties = propertyPath.Split('.').ToArray();
        var value = Expression.Property(parExp, properties[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            value = Expression.Property(value, properties[i]);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

this code takes the propertyPath (ex: x.User.Department.Id)
and returns the value,

The problems here:

1. I cannot pass a nullable object if the list isn't nullable too
2. I am not quite sure weather it's the right way to access properties

so my question is what is the solution for these problems?

Comment: Do you *need* `List<TSearch>` or just `IEnumerable<TSearch>`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not just using IQueryable.Where ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman IEnumerable<TSearch> since I wanna deal with queryable type too

Comment: @Sergey just saving lines, cleaner code, I've like 10 list to filter, 
each one needs to be checked if it's null or has no items
that's a lot of lines!!